# Proving a complex number is differentiable using the limit definition

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

**Question:**

$f(x+iy) = xy^3$ Prove that $f(x+iy)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

**My Attempt:**

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h}.$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^4-0}{h}.$$

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{\ h^3} =0$$

Therefore f(x+iy) is differentiable with derivative 0.

Would this be correct? Thanks!

Comment: That's not correct; you're only computing a directional derivative, not a (Frechet) differential.

Comment: What is the co domain of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like that. Instead:
$$
0\le\left|\frac{xy^3-0}{x+iy-0}\right|=\frac{|xy^3|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le(x^2+y^2)^{3/2},
$$
since $|x|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The right-hand side $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$ converges to zero when $x+iy\to0$. So $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: How would you use the limit definition in this case? What would your f(z+h) term be?

Comment: I used precisely the definition of limit. Note that $z=0$ and $h=x+iy$, and so $f(z+h)=xy^3$.